# Is there a way to switch to Reply All after pressing Reply in Outlook 2013?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Sometimes I press reply in Outlook and start composing a message, but half way in realize that there were other recipients in the original and I want to reply to them all instead of just the sender. In Gmail you can press Reply All while replying and it will change the recipients, but this doesn't work in Outlook. So I'm forced to copy the text I've written, discard the message, press Reply All and paste it.

Is there a way to switch from Reply to Reply All more seamlessly (the way Gmail does)?

Comment: Could this be done with a script/macro?

Comment: I'm up-voting this question as if it were a feature request for all email systems, lol.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not a "one button click" way to do this.

You have two options:

1. Copy the recipients of the original mail and paste them into the "Cc" field of the new mail you are composing.
2. As you said yourself, copy the text you have written, and start over by using "Reply all".

The first option would probably be easiest.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no easy way to do this, other than starting again.

In the reply message push Ctrl A to select all the text and your signature(if any) followed by Ctrl X to cut the text/images from your email.

Then close the reply window.

Click the original message then reply all.

In the new reply all message window Ctrl A to select all the text including the signature then Ctrl V to paste the text/images from the previous reply.

Comment: First do a Ctrl+A before pressing Ctrl+X otherwise nothing will be copied.

Comment: Yeah sorry, was answering past my bedtime last night.

Comment: Generally I have a habit of waiting until I paste the text in the new message before closing the old one, in case I forgot ctrl-a or, for some other reason, the text wasn't actually copied.

Answer (score -1):

Close your Reply draft and save your work. Reopen the same draft as Reply All and those extra recipients should now be added.

Comment: There's no way to do this in my Outlook, all the _Reply..._ options are greyed out when I have a draft.